# use ffmpeg to pull the rtsp video stream, and then directly push the rtmp stream，but Segmentation fault appears

Tags: ffmpeg

Use ffmpeg to get the rtsp video stream. The resolution of the video stream is 2688*1520 and the frame rate is 25fps. The simplest process is to use ffmpeg to pull the rtsp video stream, and then directly push the rtmp stream, but in the process of pushing the stream Segmentation fault appears, the code is as follows:

```
    AVPacket packet;
    av_init_packet(&packet);
    int start_time = 0;
    start_time=av_gettime();
    int frame_index = 0;
    while(1){
            // AVPacket packet;

            AVStream* rtsp_stream;
            AVStream* rtmp_stream;
            ret_f = av_read_frame(av_fc_input, &packet);
            if (ret_f < 0)
            {
                    break;
            }
            INFO_LOG("av_read_frame to packet success");
            rtsp_stream = av_fc_input->streams[packet.stream_index];
            rtmp_stream = av_fc_output->streams[packet.stream_index];

            if(rtsp_stream->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO){
                    AVRational time_base = rtsp_stream->time_base;
                    AVRational time_base_q = AV_TIME_BASE_Q;
                    int64_t pts_time = av_rescale_q(packet.dts, time_base, time_base_q);
                    int64_t now_time = av_gettime() - start_time;
                    if(pts_time > now_time)
                            av_usleep(pts_time - now_time);
            }
            INFO_LOG("get input and output");

            packet.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(packet.pts, rtsp_stream->time_base, rtmp_stream->time_base, AVRounding(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
            packet.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(packet.dts, rtsp_stream->time_base, rtmp_stream->time_base, AVRounding(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF |AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
            packet.duration = av_rescale_q(packet.duration, rtsp_stream->time_base, rtmp_stream->time_base);

            packet.pos = -1;

            INFO_LOG("packet parameter edit success");
            if(packet.stream_index == video_stream){
                    ERROR_LOG("Send %d video frames to out URL", frame_index);
                    ++frame_index;
            }

            INFO_LOG("frame index ++ success");

            ret_f = av_interleaved_write_frame(av_fc_output, &packet);
            if (ret_f < 0)
            {
                    ERROR_LOG("Error muxing packers");
                    break;
            }

            INFO_LOG("write packet to av_fc_output success");

            av_packet_unref(&packet);
            // usleep(40*1000);
    }
```

Why does a segfault occur? Is it because the resolution is too large?
Is there any solution? resize image?
thank you！

Answer (score 0):

In addition, this problem does not occur when I use the sub-stream of the camera. The corresponding resolution of the sub-stream is 704*576 and the frame rate is 25fps.